# How to calculate count of rows of Memory-Optimized Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index, performance, memory-optimized-tables, query-performance

Performance is important for me so I don't use `select count(*) from MyTable`.

I use the following query to calculate rows count:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
[Tables].name AS [TableName],
SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
-- WHERE [Tables].name = N'name of the table'
GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), [Tables].name;
```

Basically it works well for pretty much all `sql server` versions. It doesn't work for `Memory-Optimized Tables`. I create a table using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemoryTableSchemaAndData]
(
    [column_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [column_varchar] [varchar](100) COLLATE French_CS_AS NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [column_id] ASC
)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[MemoryTableSchemaAndData] VALUES 
(100, '-'),
(101, '-'),
(102, '-');
```

The query below shows that `index_id` equals to 2 for M`emory-Optimized Table`:

```
select object_Name(object_id), *
from sys.partitions
where OBJECTPROPERTYEX (OBJECT_ID, N'TableIsMemoryOptimized') = 1
```

But `sys.partitions` doesn't contain rows count for `Memory-Optimized Tables` at all. The following query as a prove:

```
SELECT rows, *
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
WHERE [Tables].name = N'MemoryTableSchemaAndData'

--it returns rows 0
```

How to calculate rows count for `Memory-Optimized Table` ?

ps: already tried [this](https://raresql.com/tag/simple-way-to-count-number-of-records-in-memory-optimized-table/) following solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your query works fine for me to display the number of records in a memory-optimized table. What version and patch level of SQL Server are you using? 

Depending on the version of SQL Server, sp_spaceused will not work correctly.

Comment: @NedOtter `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
 Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: I would strongly advise you to patch or upgrade that server. It is two service packs behind, and since 2014 was the 1.0 release of Hekaton, there are tons of bugs that were fixed.